# JPA: Event notification during persisting/updating a child?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, events

I have two entities A and B. A has a many-to-one association towards B (A.listOfBs::List). I want to validate before B is persisted if a B was added to an already existing A.

Debugging into our JPA implementation (Hibernate), I learned that it basically cascades the association and while knowing its a parent<->child association only invokes the PrePersist-handler on B and never the BeforeUpdate on A.

Since I do not want to introduce a bi-directional mapping, I would like to know how I can validate A's children during B's persisting phase as A has special requirements (no two childs sharing the same type).

Is there any mechanism I can learn about parent<->child related events revolving around persisting or deleting children of a particular parent?

Answer (score 0):

From debugging into Hibernate (another framework might be different), the persist event is handled solely on a per entity level. There is a mapping between child and parent in the persistence context that is set prior to persisting the entity (see handling/persisting an association). If one is able to access it, it would be possible for the child to notify its parent event even without a bi-directional connection. All this will continue to feel like a hack.

The best solution seems to be to listen to session level events and iterate through the list of managed entities an let those be validated regardless whether those have changed or not.